# Force Netbeans to generate partially-qualified javadoc

Tags: netbeans, javadoc

several methods I have return Map objects like (partially-qualified)

```
Map<Integer,String>
```

which turn out in the NetBeans (7.0.1) generated javadoc as fully-qualified:

```
java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer>
```

Do you know whether it's possible (and how) to tell NetBeans javadoc generator to use partially-qualified class names? Through Google I was only able to find related [Oracle's naming convetion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#terminology) but there seems to be no useful option switch.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved to post-production modification of javadoc generated files with this simple grep & sed command. It is platform dependent though (*nix os):

For example, to hide all "java.lang" package prefixes, run this in javadoc directory:

```
grep -rl "java.lang." ./ | xargs sed -i 's/java.lang.//g'
```

And in the same fashion with "java.util." package:

```
grep -rl "java.util." ./ | xargs sed -i 's/java.util.//g'
```

Hope it helps someone out there.